# How can i add dynamic validation for inputbox?? using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my problem..

I have the option to create(add) two new input fields, as many times you want,at the same time i want to validate the input fields which are opened. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you are using a function `.validate()` to attach the Validation Handler to the form. When you create a new field, you might be calling a function, say `newField()`. In that, call the `.validate()` function again?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").validate();
});
```

In the JavaScript, where you insert:

```
<input type="button" onclick="newField(); $("form").validate();" />
```

So each time a new element is inserted, it will call the `.validate()` function. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using jquery validation plugin, can u suggest me for that..! any how ur thing is good for the general purpose..!!

Comment: Just saw your message. Guess you have already got your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you give each of your input elements the same class attribute, you can easily iterate over all of them in a validation function.

```
function validateElements(){
  var invalidElements = [];
  $(".elementToValidate").each(function(index,elem){
    if ($(elem).val() == ''){
      // this element can not be validated! (perhaps add an indication on the page)
      invalidElements.push($(elem));
    }
  });

  if (invalidElements.length){
    return false; // there are invalid elements!  Can not validate.
  }
  return true; // Validated!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ya when do u want me to call validateElements function as i am running other validation script for the remaining fields in form. under document ready function

Comment: @sid - where ever you think it is right!  All I am doing here is validating that the element has some text in it - that's all.  You might need to customize this to your needs, but its 100% up to you where to call this function.  Before or after the other validation scripts.